# Android Login with Google Plus Account

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-signin

I successfully logged into my Google Plus Account using Google+ API following this tutorial:

[Android Login with Google Plus Account](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

and got some of the user's information (Name, Email, plus Profile URL, Image etc..).

The problem I faced is that I can't get user's activities (I mean the last posts on user's "wall").
I know that using Google Plus API I can only get public activities however I'm not able even to get those.
The code I'm using is

```
            // This sample assumes a client object has been created.
            // To learn more about creating a client, check out the starter:
            //  https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java
            Plus.Activities.List listActivities = plus.activities().list("me", "public");
            listActivities.setMaxResults(5L);

            // Execute the request for the first page
            ActivityFeed activityFeed = listActivities.execute();

            // Unwrap the request and extract the pieces we want
            List<Activity> activities = activityFeed.getItems();

            // Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
            while (activities != null) {
                for (Activity activity : activities) {
                    System.out.println("ID " + activity.getId() + " Content: " +
                            activity.getObject().getContent());
                }

                // We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is null.
                // If this is the case, break.
                if (activityFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
                    break;
                }

                // Prepare to request the next page of activities
                listActivities.setPageToken(activityFeed.getNextPageToken());

                // Execute and process the next page request
                activityFeed = listActivities.execute();
                activities = activityFeed.getItems();
            }
```

And I got it form Google+ API official website at this address:

[Google+ Platform: Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list)

When ever I try to compile and run I get the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(207, 21) error: cannot find symbol class Activities
Error:(207, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable plus
Error:(211, 17) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityFeed
Error:(214, 17) error: cannot find symbol class List
Error:(219, 60) error: cannot find symbol method getId()
Error:(220, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getObject()
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/

Answer (score 0):

The example you used is using the (google-api-services-plus..jar) API from https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java.git whereas your application is using the Android Google Messaging Services API.

I'm guessing your Plus import is com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus? (Which is what you want to use on Android)

You probably want to use the Plus.MomentsApi API, see https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities.

Comment: I'm trying to get posts from the user, not to write on their google+ wall. this is what I found in the documentation you linked in you replay: "Note: The moment methods do not write directly to a user's Google+ stream. They instead write to a user's profile, and are not necessarily viewable by others depending on the user's preferred sharing settings." I don't want to "write to user's profile"/